# Query for fetching the count of records each month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch the count of records entered in each month of the financial year

For example, I have declared a column called issue in `varchar` because the data what I am taking is issues of the particular machine. And for example, let's say one issue is raised in July month I enter the data as 'Jul 19-1' and the again issue is raised in the month of September again I go back to the issue happened in July and enter the data as 'sep19-2'.

So in the backend, it takes as `jul19-1 sep19-2`

What can be the query that I can write for counting the number of issues raised in each month

I tried the below query but

```
    SELECT COUNT(month_nc) 
    FROM `ncr` 
    WHERE month_nc='Jul18-1'
```

In some months there will be only one issue so I can the count of the month given in the above query

What will be the query if I want to fetch the count of each month

```
id  issue     issue_month 
1    bearing   jul18-1
               sep18-2
2    motor     jul18-2
3    battery   apr18-3
```

ps: issue_month is declared in varchar(10)

Comment: Why not simply store the date on which issue was raised in a proper `date` field ? I believe that before insert a new issue, you are unncessarily fetching the last records; processing it and then inserting the new issue... This all can be done away with, if you simply store the date on which issue was raised.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya my initial plan was that i have created the date column but the clients have the previous financial year data and previous month data.  Some issues that are raised in the last year are raised in this year.How can I fetch that data?

Comment: You can simply consider the first date of the month for previous data as issue date.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I can understand your comment but the previous years data was inserted recently so the date stored is recently inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two methods.  One using strings:

```
select left(issue_month, 5), count(*)
from t
group by left(issue_month, 5), count(*)
```

This will not order the values correctly.

You can convert to a date to order properly:

```
order by str_to_date(concat('01', left(issue_month, 5)), '%d%b%y')
```

Or, represent the dates correctly:

```
select str_to_date(concat('01', left(issue_month, 5)), '%d%b%y') as yyyymm, count(*)
from t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do to split your issue_month into "month_year" and "issue_count"

yourTable

[image]

```
select id, 
issue, 
issue_month, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(issue_month, '[^-]+', 1) as month_year,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(issue_month, '[^-]+', 1,2 ) as issue_count 
from yourTable;
```

[image]

Now you can aggregate the issue_count across issues or year_months or any other field in your table.

For example, to get the sum of all the issues for any given month_year

```
    select 
        month_year, 
        sum(issue_count) issue_count 
        from
    (select 
     id, issue, issue_month, 
     REGEXP_SUBSTR(issue_month, '[^-]+', 1) as month_year,
     REGEXP_SUBSTR(issue_month, '[^-]+', 1,2 ) as issue_count 
     from yourTable) foo
     group by  month_year;
```

[image]

Comment: `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'REGEXP_SUBSTR'` I am using the `phpmyadmin` and getting this error for both the queries